# Starred unpacking in subscription index

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
class A:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print(key)
a = A()
a[*(1,2,3)]
```

With python 3.10.6, I get a `SyntaxError : invalid syntax` at the starred unpacking on the last line. On python 3.11.0, however, the code works fine and prints `(1,2,3)`, as one could *maybe* expect.

As far as I can tell, there is no difference in the language reference between the two versions regarding the syntax of subscriptions (sections 6.3.2 of the references are identical), and no mention of this change appears in the 3.11 changelog. Also, looking at these reference the behavior of 3.10.6 seem consistent (the expression between brackets should be an `expression_list`, which does not allow for starred unpacking).

Is this a bug in the 3.11 version, or is this syntax change documented somewhere?

Comment: maybe you should send this to authors of python on python.org or https://bugs.python.org/

Comment: did you check [What’s New In Python 3.11 — Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html) ? Maybe there is information about changes

Comment: BTW: if you checked some documentation then in question you could add links to documentation

Comment: I used Python 3.12.0rc3. No issue problem so far.

Comment: @toyotaSupra The question is clear that this is a new change in behavior between 3.10 and 3.11. Thus, it makes sense that this snippet will run in 3.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this change was introduced in 3.11 as a part of grammar changes for [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#change-1-star-expressions-in-indexes).

Relevant quote:

> To put it another way, note that `x[..., *a, ...]` produces the same result as `x[(..., *a, ...)]` (with any slices `i:j` in `...` replaced with `slice(i, j)`, with the one edge case that x[*a] becomes `x[(*a,)])`.

The relevant PR appears to be [bpo-43224 (#31018)](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/31018).

The changeset was [bpo-43224 (#87390)](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87390).

---

That this is an implication of PEP 646 is not obvious to me (until you read around a bit). [PEP 637](https://peps.python.org/pep-0637/) was rejected but it appears to deal with this more directly.  In the [rejection discussion for PEP 637](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/thread/6TAQ2BEVSJNV4JM2RJYSSYFJUT3INGZD/), Guido van Rossum says:

> Let me clarify what the typing-sig folks wanted out of this PEP. We only
> care about adding support for `x[*y]` (including things like `x[a, *b, c]`). We'll just update PEP 646 to add that explicitly there and hope that
> PEP 646 fares better than PEP 637.

One last bit of trivia: I found this by looking through the pyright repo, which initially added this support in response to PEP 637 ([commit](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/commit/e70c86f37258cdbc0d21b0b4f4c177c11714bfce)). It appears that this was subsequently updated to reflect the actual changes that went into 3.11 ([commit](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/commit/c2258ccb539b385fffdac97530ac6452460715e9)).

Answer (score 1):

This syntax became valid after [PEP646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#change-1-star-expressions-in-indexes) implementation:

> The first grammar change enables use of star expressions in index operations (that is, within square brackets), necessary to support star-unpacking of TypeVarTuples:

```
DType = TypeVar('DType')
Shape = TypeVarTuple('Shape')
class Array(Generic[DType, *Shape]):
    ...
```

> Before:

```
slices:
    | slice !','
    | ','.slice+ [',']
```

> After:

```
slices:
    | slice !','
    | ','.(slice | starred_expression)+ [',']
```